# D3. Why is my group translation not working?

Tags: d3.js

My goal here is to translate a group of svg elements with a translation. It is not working. Here is the code:

Create an SVG container

```
// create svg container
canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",   canvasBBox.width)
    .attr("height", canvasBBox.height);
```

Append a translation of x=200, y=200

```
// apply a transform
canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return scarpa.translate(200, 200); });
```

Add a box

```
  // render a background
    canvas.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width",   canvasBBox.width)
        .attr("height", canvasBBox.height)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return scarpa.rgb_SVG(0,255,0); });
```

Add a y-axis

```
// render y-axis
canvas.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { return scarpa.grey_SVG(64); })
    .attr("x1", histogram.xScale(0))
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", histogram.xScale(0))
    .attr("y2", canvasBBox.height);
```

The box + y-axis line never translates. For a sanity check I applied the translation direction to the box and it did translate. Sigh.

I am assuming the group translation implies a local coordinate system within with x = y = 0 would be the origin of the translated coordinate frame. No? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that the `.append()` function does not change the selection that it is called on, but returns a new selection.

Therefore the `g` element gets appended to the `svg` and the `rect` gets also appended to the `svg` and not inside the translated `g` element. You should see this if you inspect the `svg` output.

There are two possible solutions:
1: If you want to translate everything, append the `g` element in the first statement like so:

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",   canvasBBox.width)
    .attr("height", canvasBBox.height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return scarpa.translate(200, 200); });

canvas.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width",   canvasBBox.width)
    .attr("height", canvasBBox.height)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return scarpa.rgb_SVG(0,255,0); });

canvas.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
  .append("line")
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { return scarpa.grey_SVG(64); })
    .attr("x1", histogram.xScale(0))
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", histogram.xScale(0))
    .attr("y2", canvasBBox.height);
```

2: If you want to append something outside of the translated group, 
assign the groupselection to a new variable like so:

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",   canvasBBox.width)
    .attr("height", canvasBBox.height);

var canvasGroup = canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return scarpa.translate(200, 200); });

canvasGroup.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width",   canvasBBox.width)
    .attr("height", canvasBBox.height)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return scarpa.rgb_SVG(0,255,0); });

canvasGroup.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
  .append("line")
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { return scarpa.grey_SVG(64); })
    .attr("x1", histogram.xScale(0))
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", histogram.xScale(0))
    .attr("y2", canvasBBox.height);
```

Comment: if you take a closer look, you will see that i combined your first two statements into one statement by method chaining. this way, the returned selection of `append("g")` and not the selection with `append("svg")` will be stored inside the `canvas` variable

Comment: Actually your nested transformation solution is 2 not 1. I tried it and it works. Please make the change for others reading along. Cheers.

Comment: oh i see, solution 1 had a semicolon in the third line that should not have been there. I removed the semicolon, now both solutions should do the job by nesting the elements inside the `g` element that gets transformed